# Netbeans not filling junction table using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

I'm new at working with Hibernate but I need to use it for a project at work. We're using Netbeans with Derby Embedded and we can't change to a different IDE.

The problem I'm having is related to a many-to-many relationship in the database.

I have a table PROBLEM, a table MACHINE and a junction table MACHINEPROBLEM. A Problem can have many machines, and a Machine can have many problems. Those tables are related through the junction table MACHINEPROBLEM.

I have the necessary POJOs and mapping files (appropriately referenced in hibernate.cfg.xml) and let Netbeans and Hibernate automatically create the tables in the database.
The tables and respective relationships were created correctly. Table MACHINEPROBLEM has a composite key composed of "machineid" which references "id" in the MACHINE table, and "problemid" which references "id" in the PROBLEM table.

What's happening is that when I create a Problem object, add a Set of Machine to it, and then save it in the database the junction table isn't being filled with any data. The data is saved correctly in both the PROBLEM and MACHINE tables, but the MACHINEPROBLEM table is empty. This means I can't search for all the machines of a given problem, since the junction table used to connect them is empty.

Can anyone please help me solve this problem? Thanks.

**Mapping files:**

Machine.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="DataAccess.entity.Machine" table="MACHINE" schema="APP">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <set name="problems" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" table="MACHINEPROBLEM">
         <key column="MACHINEID"/>
         <many-to-many column="PROBLEMID" class="DataAccess.entity.Problem"/>
        </set>
        <property name="machineid" type="string">
            <column name="MACHINEID" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Problem.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="DataAccess.entity.Problem" table="PROBLEM" schema="APP">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <set name="machines" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" table="MACHINEPROBLEM">
         <key column="PROBLEMID"/>
         <many-to-many column="MACHINEID" class="DataAccess.entity.Machine"/>
        </set>
        <property name="problemid" type="string">
            <column name="PROBLEMID" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="problemname" type="string">
            <column name="PROBLEMNAME" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="tipoproblema" type="string">
            <column name="TIPOPROBLEMA" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="linear" type="boolean">
            <column name="LINEAR" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="numtarefas" type="int">
            <column name="NUMTAREFAS" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="nummaquinas" type="int">
            <column name="NUMMAQUINAS" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**POJOs:**

Machine.java

```
public class Machine  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private long id;
     private String machineid;
     private Set<Problem> problems = new HashSet<Problem>();

    public Machine() {
    }

    public Machine(long id, String machineid) {
       this.id = id;
       this.machineid = machineid;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMachineid() {
        return this.machineid;
    }

    public void setMachineid(String machineid) {
        this.machineid = machineid;
    }

     public Set<Problem> getProblems() {
      return problems;
    }

    public void setProblems( Set<Problem> problems ) {
      this.problems = problems;
     }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj == null) return false;
      if (!this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) return false;

      Machine obj2 = (Machine)obj;
      if((this.id == obj2.getId()) && (this.machineid.equals(obj2.getMachineid())))
      {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
       int tmp = 0;
       tmp = ( id + machineid ).hashCode();
       return tmp;
    }
}
```

Problem.java

```
public class Problem  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private long id;
     private String problemid;
     private String problemname;
     private String tipoproblema;
     private boolean linear;
     private int numtarefas;
     private int nummaquinas;
     private Set<Machine> machines = new HashSet<Machine>();

    public Problem() {
    }


    public Problem(long id, String problemid, String problemname, boolean linear, int numtarefas, int nummaquinas) {
        this.id = id;
        this.problemid = problemid;
        this.problemname = problemname;
        this.linear = linear;
        this.numtarefas = numtarefas;
        this.nummaquinas = nummaquinas;
    }

    public Problem(long id, String problemid, String problemname, String tipoproblema, boolean linear, int numtarefas, int nummaquinas) {
       this.id = id;
       this.problemid = problemid;
       this.problemname = problemname;
       this.tipoproblema = tipoproblema;
       this.linear = linear;
       this.numtarefas = numtarefas;
       this.nummaquinas = nummaquinas;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProblemid() {
        return this.problemid;
    }

    public void setProblemid(String problemid) {
        this.problemid = problemid;
    }

    public String getProblemname() {
        return this.problemname;
    }

    public void setProblemname(String problemname) {
        this.problemname = problemname;
    }

    public String getTipoproblema() {
        return this.tipoproblema;
    }

    public void setTipoproblema(String tipoproblema) {
        this.tipoproblema = tipoproblema;
    }

    public boolean isLinear() {
        return this.linear;
    }

    public void setLinear(boolean linear) {
        this.linear = linear;
    }

    public int getNumtarefas() {
        return this.numtarefas;
    }

    public void setNumtarefas(int numtarefas) {
        this.numtarefas = numtarefas;
    }

    public int getNummaquinas() {
        return this.nummaquinas;
    }

    public void setNummaquinas(int nummaquinas) {
        this.nummaquinas = nummaquinas;
    }

    public Set<Machine> getMachines() {
      return machines;
    }

    public void setMachines( Set<Machine> machines ) {
      this.machines = machines;
     }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        try
        {
             //Adds a couple of machines to a hashset
             Set<Machine> machines = new HashSet<>();
             machines.add(new Machine(1, "M1"));
             machines.add(new Machine(2, "M2"));

             //creates a Problem with some random data
             Problem p = new Problem(2, "OSD1", "TestP", "jobshop", true, 2, 3);    
             p.setMachines(machines);

             //Adds Problem p to the database
             ProblemDAL pDal = new ProblemDAL(null); 
             pDal.add(p); //Doing this saves Problem p to table PROBLEM, as well as the set of machines to table MACHINE. However, nothing's saved in the junction table MACHINEPROBLEM.

             pDal.closeSession();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**ProblemDAL**

```
public class ProblemDAL {
    Session session;
    boolean closeSession;

    public ProblemDAL(Session session)
    {
        if(session == null)
        {
            this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }
        else
        {
            this.session = session;
        }        
    }

    public void add(Problem entity) throws Exception {
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(entity);
            tx.commit();
        } 
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    }

    public void update(Problem entity)
    {
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {            
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(entity);
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    }

    public void delete(Problem entity){
        Transaction tx = null;

        try{
           tx = session.beginTransaction();         
           session.delete(entity); 
           tx.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
           if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
           e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }



    public Problem getById(long id) {
        Transaction tx = null;
        Problem entity = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            entity = (Problem) session.get(Problem.class, id);
            tx.commit();   
        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        finally {
            return entity;
        }

    }



    public List<Problem> getAll() {
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Problem> entityList = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            entityList = session.createQuery("from Problem").list();
            tx.commit();             
        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        finally {
            return entityList;
        }
    }

    public List<Machine> getMachines() {
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Machine> entityList = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            entityList = session.createQuery("select machines from Problem").list();
            tx.commit();             
        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        finally {
            return entityList;
        }
    }

    public void closeSession()
    {
        if(this.session!=null)
        {
            this.session.close();
        }
    } 
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:DB;create=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">***</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">***</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="DataAccess/entity/Problem.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DataAccess/entity/Machine.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DataAccess/entity/Operation.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DataAccess/entity/EvaluationParameters.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DataAccess/entity/Generatedjobs.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="DataAccess/entity/Jobs.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: You will need to post some code: mappings, code where you create a new entity etc.

Comment: I've edited my post to include the necessary code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common issue for such issues is that you have not set both sides of the relationship.

Ignoring any Hibernate issues at the moment this is best practive anyway.

If you consider:

```
Problem p = new Problem();
Machine m = new Machine();
m.addProblem(p);
```

Ignoring any persistence concerns, is your domain model in a consitent state, viz. Is machine 'm' associated with problem 'p'? i.e. does p.getMachines().contains(m) return true?

So it's normally best to encapsulate these operations:

```
public class Machine{

public void addProblem(Problem p){
problems.add(p);
p.getMachines.add(this);
}


public class Problem{
public void addMachine(Machine m){
machines.add(m);
m.getProblems().add(this);
}
```

As an experiment you can try with your current code to save a new Machine with a set of Problems. Result should be as expected as Machine is the owning (non-inverse) side.

Comment: Your suggestion definitely fixed my problem. It's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Thinking about it, what you said makes perfect sense. I was thinking about things from the database perspective and didn't extend that line of though to my domain model. Thanks once again!