# Hibernate: How to remove an entry from the many-to-many table is deleted when one of the participants

Tags: hibernate

An excerpt from the mapping:

```
<entity class= "org.sm.EndpointList" >
    <table name= "ENDPOINT_LIST" />
    <attributes>
        ...
        <many-to-many name= "endpoints">
           <join-table name= "ENDPOINT_LIST_TO_ENDPOINTS" >
                  <join-column name= "fk_endpoint_list_id" nullable= "false" />
                  <inverse-join-column name= "fk_endpoint_id" nullable= "false" />
                  <unique-constraint>
                        <column-name> fk_endpoint_list_id</column-name >
                        <column-name> fk_endpoint_id</column-name >
                  </unique-constraint>
           </join-table>
           <cascade>
                  <cascade-all />
           </cascade>
        </many-to-many>
    </attributes>
</entity >


<entity class="org.sm.Endpoint">
    <table name= "ENDPOINTS"/>
    <attributes>
    ...
    </attributes>
</entity >
```

How to specify mappings for Hibernate that if he decided to execute

```
DELETE FROM ENDPOINTS WHERE id = 123
```

before that he has to execute

```
DELETE FROM ENDPOINT_LIST_TO_ENDPOINTS WHERE fk_endpoint_id = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

For cascading to work correctly in a bi-directional relationship you need to ensure that both sides of the relationship are set correctly.

See here:

[Netbeans not filling junction table using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840832/netbeans-not-filling-junction-table-using-hibernate/19855604#19855604)

Comment: I can't change a Java classes.