# Cascading not working in oneToMany, with eclipseLink

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I am working with *EclipseLink* and *JPA 2.0*.

Those are my 2 entities:

**Feeder entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_feeder")
public class Feeder implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//Staff
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idAttachedFeederFk")
private Collection<Port> portCollection;
//staff
}
```

**Port entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_port")
public class Port implements Serializable {
//staff
@JoinColumn(name = "id_attached_feeder_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private Feeder idAttachedFeederFk;
//staff
}
```

And this is my code:

```
Feeder f = new Feeder();
//staff
Port p = new Port();
p.setFeeder(f);

save(feeder); //This is the function that calls finally persist.
```

The probleme is that, only feeder is persisted and not the port. Am I missing something? And specially, in which side should I mention the cascading exactly. Given that in my database, the *port* table is referencing the *feeder* one with a foreign key.

**EDIT**

This simple piece of code worked fine with me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Address a1 = new Address();
    a1.setAddress("madinah 0");

    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setName("houssem 0");
    e1.setAddressFk(a1);

    saveEmplyee(e1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are missing the fact that Feeder knows nothing about this new Port.Call feeder.getPortCollection().add(p) before save and it will work. I would also recommend encapsulating these operations as outlined here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840832/netbeans-not-filling-junction-table-using-hibernate/19855604#19855604

Comment: But feeder is not yet managed!

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. The answer I have given is correct.

Comment: It has given me a nullpointer exception, and i think this is normal, since feeder has no portCollection yet, may be that?

Comment: Well create a constructor and initialize the collection!!!.

Comment: But this will complicate the process:(, and a simple example worked fine (look at my EDIT)

Comment: If for some strange reason you cannot initalise a new collection (I can assure this will not break anything from a JPA perspective) then your only option is to add a cascade on the @ManyToOne and call save(port) because the new Port knows about its Feeder (but not vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would expect it to work: you are attempting to save a new instance of Feeder which has no connection whatsoever to the newly created Port.

By adding the Cascade to the `@OneToMany` and calling `save(feeder)` Eclipse link would if there were an association:

1. Insert the record for the Feeder.
2. Iterate the Port collection and insert the relevant records.

As I have noted however, this new Feeder instance has no Ports associated with it.

With regard to your simple example I assume when you say it works that both the new Address and Employee have been written to the database. This is expected because you have told the Employee about the Address (`e1.setAddressFk(a1);`) and saved the Employee. Given the presence of the relevant Cascade option then both entities should be written to the database as expected.

Given this it should then be obvious that calling `save(port)` would work if the necessary cascade option was added to the `@ManyToOne` side of the relationship.

However if you want to call `save(feeder)` then you need to fix the data model. Essentially you should **always ensure that any in-memory data model is correct at any given point in time**, viz. if the first condition below is true then it follows that the second condition must be true.

```
Port p = new Port();
Feeder feeder = new Feeder();
p.setFeeder(f();

if(p.getFeeder().equals(f){
   //true
}

if(f.isAssociatedWithPort(p)){
   //bad --> returns false
}
```

This is obviously best practice anyway but ensuring the correctnes of your in-memory model should mean you do not experience the type of issue you are seeing in a JPA environment.

To ensure the correctness of the in-memory data model you should encapsulate the set/add operations.

Comment: I am really sad you wasted a lot of my time!

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate. The answer provided is correct. Sorry I wasted my time trying to help.

Comment: I tested it many times and not working. How can feeder == null and then you call feeder.removePort(port)!

Comment: The original question was about why your association was not saved. This is clearly explained and answered.  The rest of it is a rough outline about how you might encapsulate these operations. If there are any typos in that part then it is basic Java and I fail too see how any Java developer could waste any more than about 30 seconds fixing those.